# Usar Recursos electron Fora do main.js

Tags: javascript, electron, aplicação-desktop

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
É possivel chamar um dialog.showOpenWindow fora do arquivo main.js?
Gostaria de executar uma função que ao clicar em um botão especifico do meu BrowserWindow abrisse o showOpenWindow e me retornasse o caminho do arquivo especificado.
Tentei fazer fora do main.js porém o javascript não reconhecia os comando electron.
Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa chamar o dialog usando o Remote. O remote serve exatamente para chamar as funcionalidades do Main para funcionar dentro de um Renderer.

Espero ter ajudado na sua dúvidazinha :p

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const dialog = remote.dialog;
```